# Injecting jquery with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-3.7

I am trying to solve a problem i.e. highlighting the specific words which I want to highlight (dynamic) and so far got some success but facing an issue when trying to open a json file path and same code isn't working for that. Stack - python and selenium.

```
def launchBrowserAndEmbed():
  driver = driverInitialization()
  driver.get('https://worldwide.espacenet.com/3.2/rest-services/legal/publication/EP/0546789/A2.json')
  driver.execute_script("""var jquery_script = document.createElement('script'); 
        jquery_script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js';
        jquery_script.onload = function(){inst = new Mark(document.querySelector("body")); var isMarked = inst.mark("COMMUNICATION"); console.log(isMarked)};
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery_script);"""
      )
  time.sleep(5)
  #driver.execute_script('inst = new Mark(document.querySelector("body")); var isMarked = inst.mark("COMMUNICATION"); console.log(isMarked)')

  S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
  driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height'))                                                                                                               
  driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('./screenshots/take_'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+'.png')
  driver.quit()
```

Comment: I don't think onload will fire since you are injecting after a load.  Call the function manually... also not sure that injecting an src for the script would work... also not sure that the <script> tag would be evaluated... (put an alert in there to check)  You may be limited to execution of the script/text you are sending to the execute_script method.  (So you'd need to send all of jQuery, which will be pretty problematic... I'd use raw javascript instead... you can send a function and then the call to the function and it will execute.)

Comment: It's working fine for other url, but not for json url.

Comment: ahhh, I missed that.  Once the driver is sent to the json file it has no DOM, so you can't perform any driver actions but another .get()...